# What is the correct way of freeing std::thread* heap allocated memory?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stdthread

I'm declaring a pointer to a thread in my class.

```
class A{
   std::thread*    m_pThread;   
   bool StartThread();
   UINT DisableThread();
}
```

Here is how I call a function using a thread.

```
bool A::StartThread()
{
    bool mThreadSuccess = false;
    {
       try {
          m_pThread= new std::thread(&A::DisableThread, this);
          mThreadSuccess = true;
      }
      catch (...) {
         m_pDisable = false;
      }

      if(m_pThread)
      {
         m_pThread= nullptr;
      } 
   }
return mThreadSuccess;
}
```

Here is the function called by my thread spawned.

```
UINT A::DisableThread()
{
    //print something here.
    return 0;
}
```

If I call this `StartThread()` function 10 times. Will it have a memory leak?

```
for (i = 0; i<10; i++){
    bool sResult = StartThread();
      if (sResult) {
        m_pAcceptStarted = true;
      }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the rationale behind even using a pointer here in the first place? Why not just do: `std::thread m_pThread;`?

Comment: Or `std::vector<std::thread>`, since you seem to want to spawn several.

Comment: The correct way would be to *not* use pointers or dynamic allocation. Use plain assignment to a plain `std::thread` object.

Comment: @Ruks I'm handling legacy MFC code and I'm trying to migrate them to c++11/c++17.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the correct way of freeing
>
> ```
> m_pThread= new std::thread(&A::DisableThread, this);
> ```

The correct way to free a non-array object created using allocating `new` is to use `delete`.

Avoid bare owning pointers and avoid unnecessary dynamic allocation. The example doesn't demonstrate any need for dynamic storage, and ideally you should use a `std::thread` member instead of a pointer.

> If I call this StartThread() function 10 times. Will it have a memory leak?

Even a single call will result in a memory leak. The leak happens when you throw away the pointer value here:

> ```
> m_pThread= nullptr;
> ```

---

> could you add your better solution

Here's one:

```
auto future = std::async(std::launch::async, &A::DisableThread, this);
// do something while the other task executes in another thread
do_something();
// wait for the thread to finish and get the value returned by A::DisableThread
return future.get()
```

Comment: Will this code `m_pThread= nullptr;` not enough? Where I should add `delete m_pThread` in my code?

Comment: @DecryptDcode As per my answer, that assignment is what causes the memory leak. You should delete when you no longer need the `std::thread` object. But more importantly, you probably shouldn't use dynamic allocation here in the first place.

Comment: If i'm going to join the thread after exiting the for loop say, `if (m_pThread) {  if (m_pThread->joinable()) {  m_pThread->join();  } }  delete m_pThread;` will it be fine?

Comment: @DecryptDcode It would work. But it would be better without the dynamic allocation.

Comment: could you add your better solution without using dynamic allocation in your answer? So that I don't need to free the memory every time I respawn a thread.

Comment: You said every single call causes a memory leak. Does that mean that calling it 10 times will have 10 times memory leak?

Comment: @DecryptDcode Yes.

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally would prefer using a threadpool in a real project but this example should give you an idea of how you could handle threads without new/delete.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

class A
{
public:
    template<typename Fn>
    void CallAsync(Fn fn)
    {
        // put thread in vector
        m_threads.emplace_back(std::thread(fn));
    }

    ~A()
    {
        for (auto& thread : m_threads)
        {
            thread.join();
        }
    }

    void someHandler()
    {
        std::cout << "*";
    };

private:
    std::vector<std::thread> m_threads;
};

int main()
{
    A a;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        a.CallAsync([&a] { a.someHandler(); });
    }
}
```